# Modify SQL query to convert diverse NVARCHAR string to date/time format, some cases being set to NULL even though they shouldn't be?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, data-cleaning

Problem:

The goal is to update a temporary table column TempExpirationDate from NVARCHAR to DATETIME in SQL Server and then update my actual table with those values.
The date values in the column have various formats and need conversion to a standard DATETIME format. It is basically a column that has been scrapped from a website and has to undergo A LOT of clean-up in order to be in datetime format.

Pending Issue:
Despite multiple adjustments, some specific date formats are not being successfully converted even though they appear as though they should be.

While the majority of date values are successfully converted to DATETIME, specific cases, such as 'July 4, 2018 ', still result in NULL.
Despite the adjustments made in the CASE conditions, there is a challenge in identifying the specific reason for the failure in these cases.

I am parsing through data that starts off like this (sample of the different types of values in this date column)

```
2013-09-23 00:00:00
NULL
July 2  2022
NULL
May 5, 2015),
January 25, 2018.
March 7, 2019  
January 8, 2019  
September 8, 2019  
April 5  2021
January 8  2021
May 8, 2019 (
April 06  2023
January 14, 2023
July 15, 2022
July 4, 2018  
February 2016)
```

I run the following query to help clean up the dates by removing special characters for the different cases of formats we see.

```
UPDATE #TempIntermediateResults
SET TempExpirationDate =
    CASE
        -- Do nothing if the date is in the format '2013-09-23 00:00:00'
        WHEN TempExpirationDate LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
            THEN TempExpirationDate
        -- Leave as null if the date is null
        WHEN TempExpirationDate IS NULL
            THEN NULL
        -- Remove special characters for month and year format like 'February 2016)'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, 1, CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate)), ')', '')))
            -- Remove special characters for formats like 'May 8, 2019 (' or 'May 5, 2015),'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(', TempExpirationDate) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, 1, CHARINDEX('(', TempExpirationDate)), '(', '')))
        -- Remove special characters for other cases, including "."
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(TempExpirationDate, SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', TempExpirationDate + '0'), 1), ''), '.', '')))
    END;
```

This results is this:

```
"2013-09-23 00:00:00"
NULL
"July 4 2018  "
"July 2  2022"
"February 2016"
NULL
"May 5, 2015"
"January 25 2018"
"March 7 2019  "
"January 8 2019  "
"September 8 2019  "
"April 5  2021"
"January 8  2021"
"May 8, 2019"
"April 06  2023"
"January 14 2023"
"July 15 2022"
```

Next, I run another update query to try to update those values to date/time format.

```
-- Update the temporary table 
UPDATE #TempIntermediateResults
SET TempExpirationDate =
    CASE
        -- Existing conditions
        WHEN TRY_CAST(TempExpirationDate AS DATETIME) IS NOT NULL
            THEN TRY_CAST(TempExpirationDate AS DATETIME)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(',', TempExpirationDate) > 0
            THEN TRY_CAST(REPLACE(TempExpirationDate, ',', '') AS DATETIME)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate) > 0
            THEN TRY_CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, 1, CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate)), ')', '') AS DATETIME)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(TempExpirationDate))) > 0
            THEN TRY_CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(TempExpirationDate)), ' ', '') AS DATETIME)
        ELSE '2000-12-31T00:00:00'   -- Default value if none of the conditions match. DID THIS AS A TEST VALUE TO TROUBLESHOOT IF I WOULD GET THIS DATE INSTEAD OF NULL.
    END;
```

However, my results are as follows:

```
Sep 23 2013 12:00AM
Dec 31 2000 12:00AM
NULL
Jul  2 2022 12:00AM
Feb  1 2016 12:00AM
Dec 31 2000 12:00AM
May  5 2015 12:00AM
Jan 25 2018 12:00AM
NULL
NULL
NULL
Apr  5 2021 12:00AM
Jan  8 2021 12:00AM
May  8 2019 12:00AM
Apr  6 2023 12:00AM
Jan 14 2023 12:00AM
Jul 15 2022 12:00AM
```

I have no idea why I keep getting null for the values below when it should be formatting correctly as date/time or at least setting to '2000-12-31T00:00:00' if I am NOT handling it correctly. I thought it could be the white space, but I have tested it several ways and it did not seem to impact the null value showing up.

```
"July 4 2018  "
"March 7 2019  "
"January 8 2019  "
"September 8 2019  "
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with emphasis on minimal, we don't need to see all that code, all we need to see is an example that is failing, and the query where its failing to be converted. Many of us are not going to spent the time required to work out which original formats are failing to convert, and which line of your many queries its failing on.

Comment: Why don't you use `isnull` to fall back to your default date when NULL

Comment: If you already have an app doing the scraping, I'd do the cleanup there. SQL's string manipulation functions are somewhat limited and clunky to work with compared to, say, regular expressions in any "standard" programming language.

Comment: Could it be the case that you have some "special" characters that appear as white space but are actually something else?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any obvious problems but having done similar exercises myself, can offer a few tips.

When you are doing data cleansing, it is extremely helpful to do it in small steps and save intermediate results for debugging purposes.

My suggestion that instead of updating the same column over and over you either save results to a new temp table for each step or store them in their own columns.

Avoid combining multiple operations into one e.g.

```
TRY_CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, 1, CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate)), ')', '') AS DATETIME)
```

should be two separate steps:

**Step #1**:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TempExpirationDate, 1, CHARINDEX(')', TempExpirationDate)), ')', '')
```

to remove invalid characters

**Step #2**:

```
TRY_CAST(...)
```

would be trying to do the conversion.

If you follow these suggestions you should be able to find problems quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(datetime, 'July 4 2018  ')       -- returns '2018-07-04 00:00:00.000'
select convert(datetime, 'March 7 2019  ')      -- returns '2019-03-07 00:00:00.000'
select convert(datetime, 'January 8 2019  ')    -- returns '2019-01-08 00:00:00.000'
select convert(datetime, 'September 8 2019  ')  -- returns '2019-09-08 00:00:00.000'
```